# What's the differences between arm-eabi-gcc and arm-elf-gcc?

Tags: arm

What's the differences between arm-eabi-gcc and arm-elf-gcc?
Can they both compile the same source code for cortex-m3 arch?

Answer (score 12):

`arm-elf-gcc` is the old toolchain supporting legacy floating-point accelerator (FPA) and the mixed-endian floating-point format.

`arm-eabi-gcc` is the newer geneartion of toolchain supporting VFP floating-point format.

I imagine they can *compile* the same source, but the later one is newer so that must be richer feature wise. What you want to hear depends on which OS / libraries you are compiling against. Toolchain, fundamental libraries and OS go arm in arm. They need to have same ABIs.

Comment: ELF stands for Executable and Linkable Format.